# When and where is a process named in Linux

Tags: linux-kernel

I've been trying to follow the flow of process creation on Linux.
So far, I've put in a few debug `printk`'s to understand pid allocation on the Linux kernel.
However, now I wish to map PIDs to binaries as they are being created (or executed).

I know that the way Linux creates processes is by forking off init and then doing an exec..or doing an exec directly from init..

I'm trying to trace when and where the field `comm` on the new `task_struct` is being filled..
The `comm` field stores the binary being executed.
So far, no matter where I try to print the `comm` field (execept during the `context_switch` function), all processes always display their name as `khelper`

I've tried extensively debugging the `do_execve` function, but that just doesn't seem to contain code related to changing of the `comm` field..

Could someone point out where and when the `comm` field is assigned

Comment: I don't remember the name of the function off the top of my head but I can try and find it for you. It's the function that actually reads the ELF file.

Comment: I believe the function that you're talking about is infact the do_execve as of linux 2.6.35 (This is the version I'm working with)..
Sadly, I could find no change to the `comm` field

Comment: I know about `do_execve`, I meant `load_elf_binary`. Check my answer for the function that actually fills the `comm` field though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correction: The function is `setup_new_exec` in `fs/exec.c` it calls `set_task_comm` which actually sets this field.

Comment: @user1761555 There are two of them defined in the same file, find the other one and try that one.

Comment: There is another fill_psinfo declared in a file called `fs/binfmt_elf_fdpic.c` but that file isn't even included during compilation

Comment: @user1761555 Try this one, I was thinking of core dumps before.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that `setup_new_exec` in `fs/exec.c` fills in the `comm` field in the struct `task_struct` for most user processes.
However, this does not seem to happen for a lot of processes that are started within the kernel itself..

Comment: Because the kernel usually starts worker threads and such which are named somewhere in `kthread_create`